# Is this the right way to do fade in while sliding down in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, fadein, effects, slidedown, jquery-effects

CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.some_class').slideDown(1000).fadeIn(5000);
});
```

Using the one above, I want to slideDown a div while having it fadeIn.  The one above doesn't seem to work.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.some_class').stop(true).fadeIn({
        duration: 5000,
        queue: false
    }).css('display', 'none').slideDown(1000);
 });
```

### Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/CXsZn/1/)**

The problem is that both [**.fadeIn()**](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [**.slideDown()**](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) need the element to have `display:none;`and when one of them starts it removes that and uses opacity, the second effect will not run because the `display` is not `none` anymore.

So if you stop the animation and re-insert the display none before running the last effect they will run "side by side".

Just in case you want, **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/CXsZn/2/)** is a demo with image

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.some_class').animate({
        "height": "show",
        "marginTop": "show",
        "marginBottom": "show",
        "paddingTop": "show",
        "paddingBottom": "show",
        "opacity": 1
    }, 3000);
});
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/sE97R/1/

Answer (score -1):

Make sure element with "some_class" class is loaded properly and it is initially hidden

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.some_class').fadeIn(1000).slideDown(1000);
});
```